# Apply one macro to another sheet/workbook regardless of sheet or workbook name

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have an issue with macros returning errors, and I was wondering if you guys could shed some light on this issue.

The macro I have looks like the following:

```
Sub pivot1_macro()
'
' pivot1_macro Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+M
'
Sheets.Add
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "7-14 week!R1C2:R199C35", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="Sheet5!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable3", DefaultVersion _
    :=xlPivotTableVersion15
Sheets("Sheet5").Select
Cells(3, 1).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("PartMOD")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("EnteredShift")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Defect")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable3").PivotFields("Defect Quantity"), "Sum of Defect Quantity", xlSum
Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("B3").Select
Range("B3").Select
End Sub
```

I'd like to apply this macro to any active worksheet, but I'm not quite sure
how to make set `'SourceData'` to current active worksheet.

Comment: remove the sheet name`7-14 week!`?

Comment: Quick note, it's [best to avoid `.Activate`/`.Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros), as it can cause unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use '&' to concatenate strings, so wouldn't

```
SourceData := ActiveSheet.Name & "!R1C2:R199C35"
```

work for you to get the current sheet's name?